# Number of Possible length $n$ messages that can be constructed using elements from a finite set?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, information-theory

My question is fairly simple, but I'm confused on how to solve it.

We are given a set $S = \{x_1, x_2, x_3 \ldots, x_m\}$. We need to construct a message (or vector) of length $n$ using the elements from the set $S$. Also, you can repeat values.

How many possible messages (or vectors) of length $n$ can be constructed using elements from set $S$, given that the number of times $x_i$ occurs is $n_i$ (or probability of occurrence of $x_i$ is $p_i = \frac{n_i}{n}$).

I would really appreciate any comments.

Comment: Which is it?  You want exactly $n_i$ occurrences of $x_i$?  Or you want each position to be randomly chosen independently of the others and the probability of it being $x_i$ is $p_i$?  In the first, see [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).  In the second, every sequence is possible including where they were all $x_1$ or all $x_2$ etc and the information about $n_i$ and $p_i$ is irrelevant and can be ignored.

Comment: I want exactly $n_i$ occurrence of $x_i$.

Comment: Yes, and so as alluded to previously, the answer is simply the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_m} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_m!}$